# CakePHP Shell - model function always empty

Tags: git, shell, cakephp

I have a job queue which sends emails.

Database:

```
id | function | arguments | description | status | error | error_count
```

e.g.

```
1
email
{"to":"test@domain.com","subject":"Email from us", "body":"Hey, how are you?"}
pending

0
```

It is processed via a shell.

```
function main(){
    App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

    $this->out('Starting Queue...');

    $this->out('...getting jobs');
    $queueJobs = $this->QueueJob->getJobs();

    if(!empty($queueJobs)) {
        //process queue
    } else {
        $this->out('......no jobs to process');
    }
}
```

The code works fine on the development site (manual upload) but when I move it to the production site (on the same server just different domain - pulled from git) $queueJobs is always empty so does not process the queue.

The model has this:

```
function getJobs(){
    $queueJobs = $this->find('all', array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'OR' => array(
                array('status'=>'pending'),
                array('status'=>'error')
            )
        )
    ));

    return $queueJobs;
}
```

I created a controller/view that also calls this model function and that works fine, it is only when using the shell that it always returns empty.

```
public function index()
{
    $queueJobs = $this->QueueJob->getJobs();
    $this->set('queueJobs', $queueJobs);
}
```

Comment: `function getJobs(){` That should really be [a finder](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types). Also note you can just do `'conditions' => ['stataus' => ['pending', 'error']]`. You should check _during execution_ what db it's talking to and determine why it finds no data; because from what you've described the code is working correctly.

Comment: I originally had the conditions like that but changed it while debugging - I will look into finders. You were spot on with the database, the db construct switches to live if it detects the URL - obviously via shell there is no URL so had to add a getcwd check too. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Please self-answer and accept - great that you found the cause =).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to AD7six for pointing me in the right direction.

The shell was looking at the wrong database as there is a dev and live database which is switched depending on the URL. Updating the construct to include a directory check solved the issue:

```
public function __construct() {
    $dir = APP;
    $live_dir = '/home/admin/domains/livedomain.com/public_html';

    if (isset($_SERVER) && isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) or isset($dir)) {
        if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'livedomain.com' or strpos($dir, $live_dir) !== FALSE) {
            $this->default  = $this->live;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw - it's _not_ a good idea to use a config switch like that - make your config static, and apply to the one environement it's installed on. It's implied you have the same config files locally and on the server - that's what not to do. +1.